# 'Select All Visible' vs 'Select All' with pagination

Tags: data-tables, pagination

Suppose I have a table with pagination due a lot of row entries. Should the default action for 'Select all' select the entries on the current page or all entries in the entire table (i.e. all pages)?

What is the intended behaviour for a user?

I am aware of the solution that Gmail has to address this where it selects the ones in view and prompts an action to select all. Just wondering where I could find some other examples of products tackling this.

Answer (score 3):

Logic and user expectation (speaking from experience with long lists in back-offices) would want to select all that actually is in view and act on it. I dont want to risk deleting or doing other actions on any other items I can't see.

If I want to act on everything at the same time, I would appreciate an option to show everything at once on the page, so I can select all and maybe unselect the few items I dont want to act on. But that option depends on your technical limitations.

Does your list have a very high number of items that would require too much ressources to load and display at once ? If that's the case this option is not viable. But in any case I think it's bad practice to act on items you can't see. Especially if the action is irreversible.

If not possible, select all by groups of 10/20/40/100/200 per page is quite enough. You would just have to let them select the number of items they can show on one page.
Hope that helps ! Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we don't know the intended behaviour for your user. That is something you will have to ask them in this context. You could make sure your labelling is clear what the action that follows will be:

[] Select all entries (3,495)

[] Select page 1 entries